# Apply function on multiple columns and create new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function on multiple columns in a pandas dataframe where I compare the value of two columns to create a third new based on this comparison. The code runs, however, the output does not get correct. For example, this code:

```
def conditions(x,column1, column2):
    if x[column1] != x[column2]: 
        return "incorrect"
    else:
        return "correct"


lst1=["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
lst2=["col1_1","col2_2","col3_3","col4_4","col5_5"]

i=0
for item in lst2: 
    df[str(item)+"_2"] = df.apply(lambda x: conditions(x,column1=x[item], column2=x[lst1[i]]) , axis=1) 
    i=i+1
```

The output should be that the first row contains an incorrect instance, but it marks it as correct.

This is how the output looks:
[image]

The correct would be that col4_4_2 and col5_5_2 should be marked as incorrect. This is how it should look:
[image]

Is it not possible to apply a function in this way on multiple columns and pass the column name as arguments in pandas? If so, how should it be performed?

Comment: Please include a sample. You probably should be using vectorized operations instead of apply on `axis=1`.

Comment: @enke, what do you mean by sample? I provided an example of the first row for each column and the output. I want to compare the value for each column-pair, in this case an integer comparison. Thus, col4 =1 and was predicted in col4_4 as 0, and this comparison should generate "incorrect", but it does not with above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first had to add the columns and fill them with zeros, then apply the function.

```
def conditions(x,column1, column2):
        if x[column1] != x[column2]: 
            return "incorrect"
        else:
            return "correct"
    
    
lst1=["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
lst2=["col1_1","col2_2","col3_3","col4_4","col5_5"]
i=0
for item in lst2: 
    df[str(item)+"_2"] = 0

i=0
for item in df.columns[-5:]:
    df[item]=df.apply(lambda x: conditions(x, column1=lst1[i], column2=lst2[i]) , axis=1) 
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a df, so I used this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]],columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5','col1_1','col2_2','col3_3','col4_4','col5_5','col1_1_2','col2_2_2','col3_3_2','col4_4_2','col5_5_2',])
```

Your conditions function is expecting a dataframe and then references to two of it's columns, but you are supplying it a df and then two values. One way to solve your problem is to change your comparison function to something like this (note you don't actually need the df itself anymore):

```
def conditions(x,column1, column2):

   print(column1,column2)

   if column1 != column2: 
       return "incorrect"
   else:
       return "correct"
```

Alternatively, you could change the line with lamba in it to something like this:

```
df[str(item)+"_2"] = df.apply(lambda x: conditions(x, lst2[i], lst1[i]) , axis=1)
```